# Undefined index in PHP and data type POINT in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to using the data type POINT in MYSQL so I wanted to test an output to a table in PHP but I'm getting the error "Undefined index". How can I fix the this error and display the points in the table?

***The error message***
Notice: Undefined index: my_point in C:\xampp\htdocs\view.php on line 23

(The points do not show in the table. How can I fix this?)

***MYSQL Table***

/*Table structure for table `highcharts_php` */

```
            CREATE TABLE `highcharts_php` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `run_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
              `my_point` POINT DEFAULT NULL,
              `cur_timestamp`  TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
              SET time_zone='+00:00';
            /*Data for the table `highcharts_php` */

            insert into highcharts_php (`id`,`run_name`,`cur_timestamp`,`my_point`) values ( 1, 'SSTP Keystone COOPER','2012-06-28 00:00:01', GeomFromText( ' POINT(0.6 70.18) ' ) )
```

****PHP Code****

```
            <?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxx");
            if (!$con)
              {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
              }

            mysql_select_db("graph", $con);
            /*$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highcharts_php");*/
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT run_name,cur_timestamp, x( my_point ), y( my_point ) FROM highcharts_php LIMIT 0 , 30")or die 
            (mysql_error());
            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>run_name</th>
            <th>my_point</th>
            <th>cur_timestamp</th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['run_name'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['my_point'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['cur_timestamp'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
            echo "</table>";

            mysql_close($con);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a column alias for your two calculated columns:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT 
    run_name,
    cur_timestamp,
    /* Column aliases via AS */
    x( my_point ) AS my_point_x, 
    y( my_point ) AS my_point_y 
  FROM highcharts_php LIMIT 0 , 30") or die();
```

Access them as `$row['my_point_x'], $row['my_point_y']`.

Without column aliases, they exist in your `$row` as `$row['x( my_point )'], $row['y (my_point)']`, exactly as they appeared in your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1):

Alias the return values from `X()` and `Y()` using AS, like so:

```
X( my_point ) AS x_value, Y( my_point ) AS y_value
```

Then access them in PHP as:

```
$row['x_value']
$row['y_value']
```

Otherwise, you would have to access the column with:

```
$row['X( my_point )']
```

Or something similar to that - See [the example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_x) in the docs to see how the column name is dynamically generated based on your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT run_name,
cur_timestamp, 
CONCAT(x( my_point ), ' ', y( my_point )) as my_point 
FROM highcharts_php LIMIT 0 , 30
```